# How do I get the results of a page with jsoup?

Tags: java, kotlin, jsoup

When I publish data to the site, the required information is not returned

this website used :[text](https://musicaldown.com/en)

i need get url video tiktok

```kotlin
Thread {
                val USER_AGENT =
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
                val loginResponse= Jsoup.connect("https://musicaldown.com/en")
                    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                    .data("link_url", "https://www.tiktok.com/@islam_mch573/video/7221917367616490757")
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute()
                val doc: Document = loginResponse.parse()
                val loginCookies: Map<String, String> = loginResponse.cookies()
                println("this"+doc.text())
                runOnUiThread {
                    data.text = doc.body().text()
                }



            }.start()
```